# How to restrict NPM installs

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, malware

When discussing a [recent malware attack](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream/issues/116) using a [popular NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatmap-stream) (and after removing this package from our code base), I started to research on ways to restrict `npm install` commands. So far I have not found any way to restrict what a developer can install.

There are two reasons why this would benefit everyone:

1. Have a further layer of protection against malicious packages getting installed.
2. Avoid packages getting unintentionally installed when the package name was typo'd

Regarding #1, the idea is that each team could create an approved list of package names that could be checked against *before* `npm install` actually runs - essentially creating some type of review process for npm packages.

Regarding #2, our team was actually impacted by having this package removed on NPM - but the only reason we ever had this dependency is because a package was installed *by accident* and went unnoticed for a while. Here's what *I think* happened:

1. Developer wanted to install a package and intended to type `npm install --save somepackagehere` (*notice the dash dash*)
2. Developer accidentally typed `npm install save` (*no dash dash*), thus installing the [save](https://www.npmjs.com/package/save) npm package which has a dependency on [event-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-stream), which had a dependency on [flatmap-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatmap-stream).

---

**Node Version:** 9.9.1

**NPM Version:** 6.4.1

---

**QUESTION**

Is there an existing way to achieve what I've described above that is not dependent on a manual code-review?

Comment: *approved list of package names that could be checked against before npm install actually runs* - preinstall hook. A curated list of NPM packages? Seems to be overkill. Just review package.json changes and pay attention to `npm audit`.

Comment: instead of doing `npm install --save` you could manually edit the **package.json** file with which libraries you want. Also never use the up carrot ^ because that auto updates all packages to the next minor version. Other than that, it being vigilant about researching what you are installing. But like malware you mentioned, it has been in the package for 2-3 months and was found by accident. So no amount of research you did would have protected you from upgrading to that version unless you were being lazy and don't update your packages often.

Comment: @estus never heard of hook - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: never using the carrot is a bad solution imo, as you then forfeit the improvements (and potential security fixes) that come up later on. However it exposes you to 'upgrades' that break or pwn your stuf, but you can monitor that with `npm audit`

Comment: And just to point the obvious, unless your app is VERY simple it's irrealist to think that you'll be able to monitor all your dependencies yourself o.O you need to trust and rely on the community. Or build your own langage yourself in your garage and come up with pong in a few years ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some situations require more security and as talked about in this article (in point 6. Use a local npm proxy) you can create your own npm registry and only pull allowed packages and versions from there.

In most cases I do believe it is unnecessary however if your situation calls for this edge case it is possible.

https://snyk.io/blog/ten-npm-security-best-practices/

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, simply having code-reviews examine `package.json` changes has served the purpose of "restricting" NPM package installs.